# Would like to sync backup files on a lan cheaply and every few minutes, how?

Tags: windows-xp, backup, sync, cloud

At the moment I use sync software to copy files to other machines, so they have the same files within a matter of minues.  But the software is slow and hogs cpu time on my desktop pc.

Ideally I'd like to use a hard drive in an enclosure as a sort of mini file server, which will backup files.

This probably sounds pretty screwed up, I probably need a simple solution.

I guess I basically need to create backups of files on multiple machines and be able to access the latest version of these files on different machines.

I have tried cloud sync software but this seems quite slow or expensive.

I'd be glad to discuss possible solutions ?

Comment: DropBox. It has a LAN feature which will copy files on the same LAN pretty quickly (but it will still go into the "cloud" anyway). Check it out.

Comment: Check this: http://superuser.com/tags/sync/faq and more specifically, check out the answers to this question: http://superuser.com/questions/13493/which-is-the-best-application-to-sync-two-folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you tried a cloud sync software, which?

I'd like to mention Dropbox, it has LAN sync, so files on other machines getting updated shortly. Which amount of data you're talking about?